# What is the 2-adic expansion of 1/2?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I understand that -1/3 can be represented in 2-adics as $01010101...$, and 1/3 is just $1101010101...$. What about 1/2, though? Is it possible to represent it as an infinite expansion, or is the only way to represent 1/2 by adding "decimal places"?

Comment: 2 is not invertible as a 2-adic number. In other words 1/2 can be written only $0.1$.

Comment: @Crostul so not every fraction can be represented on 2-adics? How can I tell which can and which can't?

Comment: You seem to be writing your $2$-adic integers with the least significant digit on the left . With that notation, you are right about $1/3$, but  $-1/3$ is $10101010{\ldots}$ The invertible $2$-adic integers are the ones with least significant digit equal to $1$. (To see that this condition is necessary, note that that the least significant digit of a product is the product of the least significant digits of the factors. Sufficiency is a bit harder to prove.)

Comment: A reduced fraction $m/n$ is in $\mathbb Z_p$ if and only if $p$ does not divide $n$. Specialize to $p=2$.

Comment: OP, you ask if there's another way to represent $1/2$ besides adding "places." This is not specific to $p$-adic numbers. Think about our base-$10$ number system - how would you represent $1/10$? You make adding places sound unnatural, but it is the most natural thing to do of all. @Crostul Its inverse is not a $2$-adic *integer*. I would use $p$-adic "number" more generally to refer to elements of $\Bbb Q_p$, which are invertible when nonzero.

Comment: Just to clarify Rob Arthan's point: Exactly opposite of real numbers in base 2, 2-adics can extend infinitely to the *left*, but must terminate to the *right*. So $-1/3$ is normally written as "$\dots 010101$", not as "$01010101\dots$". However, just like in the real numbers, in 2-adics, dividing by $2$ still moves the decimal point to the left by one place, and multiplying by $2$ still moves it to the right by one place. Since $1 = \dots 000001$, we have $1/2 = \dots 00000.1 = 0.1$.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair What is confusing, then, is that 1/3 can be represented *without* needing decimal places, even though it is smaller than 1. Why would that be the case? What is the logical intuition behind that fact?

Comment: Real numbers are about order. 2-adics are about divisibility by $2$. Order isn't defined for them. When you say $\frac 13 < 1$, you are talking about real numbers, not 2-adics. $\frac 13$ and $-\frac 13$ do not terminate because the denominator is not a power of $2$, and has no digits right of the decimal point because the denominator is not divisible by $2$.

Comment: According to the $2$-adic absolute value, $1$ and $1/3$ are equally close to $0$, and $1/2$ is further away from $0$ than $1$ and $1/3$ are. In the $p$-adics, you don't measure "closeness to $0$" the same way. The metric topology is best described as an infinite $p$-ary tree (rooted at $0$ for $\Bbb Z_p$), and closeness of two $p$-adic numbers is determined by how far along the first discrepancy in their $p$-adic expansions appears.

Comment: A fraction $m/n$ has a finite base-$b$ expansion iff $n$ divides a power of $b$. Same for $p$-adic expansions. Both expansions extend finitely into large places but possibly infinitely into smaller places. Multiplying numerator / denominator by $b$ has the effect of scaling it larger / smaller and shifting digits to larger / smaller places. And for $p$-adic expansions, multiplying by $p$ has the effect of scaling smaller / larger and shifting digits to smaller / larger places. The difference is, in the reals powers of $p$ grow larger, while in the $p$-adics, powers of $p$ shrink smaller.

Comment: @runway44 that is interesting but I don't think that answer satisfies my internal confusion. To put in simple words, I'm able to implement 5-Adics as a lazy Haskell datatype representing its binary expansion, and, even though there's no sign or fractions, I can represent -1, 1/3, even i... and it just works like expected, but NOT 1/5. While I understand how that is the case, I can't grasp why, intuitively, that would be the case. Why would math have such an elegant way to implement all integers AND fractions, that covers everything, even "i"... but not 1/5?

Comment: In other words, if not for this "minor" inconvenience, "data Number = O Number | I Number" would be an extremely short, elegant and practical way to implement arbitrary precision numbers in the context of a pure functional lazy language, but just because it lacks a few fractions, it is incomplete. Implementing reals is HUGELY complex, so, being "so close" to having a great way to implement exact real arithmetic with simple algebraic datatypes is frustrating, and I'd love to understand "why" that's the case, so I can perhaps find one alternative that actually works :)

Comment: Dunno what 5-adics has to do with binary or anything else you're talking about. You can't represent 1/5 in the 5-adics with only positive powers of 5 because it is a negative power of 5. Same thing with any fraction whose denominator in simplest form is divisible by $p$ in the $p$-adics, for any prime $p$. You might as well ask why you can't represent $1$ with only positive powers of $5$, and ask why $1$ is so special. It's not special. Or you could ask why you can't write $5$ as a sum of powers of $5$ with exponents $>1$. OR write $25$ with exponents $>2$. Etc.